# v1 to v3 migration, nested tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been developing a React Native app for a little over a year and I was using v1 all along and never updated it.

> "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",

The app works just fine and is being used by the users. Now that I have some time to breathe, I decided to upgrade from v1 to v3.

In v1 I have done something like this,

```
const FacilitySearchTabs = TabNavigator({
    Property: {
        screen: PropertyTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('tabTitleProperty')
        }
    },
    Building: {
        screen: BuildingTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: I18n.t('tabTitleBuilding')
        }
    }
}, {
    ...
});

<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>

    <View style={styles.container}>

        <CustomSearchBar
            onChangeText={this.setSearchPhrase}
            onSubmitEditing={this.onSearchPress}
            placeholder={I18n.t('searchEntities')} />

        <FacilitySearchTabs
            screenProps={{
                navigation: this.props.navigation,
                searchPhrase: this.state.searchPhrase,
                onDrillDownPress: this.onDrillDownPressCallback,
                onItemPress: this.onItemPressCallback,
                selectedEntityId: selectedEntity.FmEntityId
            }} />

    </View>

</SafeAreaView>
```

I did it this way because in my UI there had to be just one search input which filters out all lists in each tab at the same time based on the user input. So regardless whether the user swipes the tabs left or right, the search input stays in place fixed.

Naturally, in v3, all I thought I had to change was how the `TabNavigator` is created but I got the following error,

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is
>   missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your
>   app container directly. More info:
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html

I have already set up my app container so that's not the issue and I know how it works, this is a screen that comes after the user has passed the initial screen.

Reading the error more closely, I did the following change,

```
<Tabs navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

and started getting a different error.

> TypeError: TypeError: No "routes" found in navigation state. Did you
>   try to pass the navigation prop of a React component to a Navigator
>   child? See
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#navigator-navigation-prop

I have followed the instructions at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#navigator-navigation-prop, the errors are gone but my tabs do not appear. Here's the code from my expo snack.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AllTab from './allTab';
import BuildingsTab from './buildingsTab';

const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  All: AllTab,
  Buildings: BuildingsTab,
});

export default class FacilitySearchScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Facility Search',
  };

  static router = {
    ...Tabs.router,
    getStateForAction: (action, lastState) => {
      // check for custom actions and return a different navigation state.
      return Tabs.router.getStateForAction(action, lastState);
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Actually, sign me out :)" onPress={this._signOutAsync} />
        <Tabs navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signOutAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
  };

  _drillDownEntity = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EntityDrillDown');
  };

  _selectEntityAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('entityId', '123');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I have 2 questions,

1. Why the tabs don't appear and how to fix it?
2. Is there a better way to achieve the same UI/UX I explained above in a better way?

[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@janithar/auth-flow-v3) is a snack I created for this. If someone is willing to look into it and help me figure this out I'll be very thankful.
In the `App.js` there's a commented piece of code which will get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a styling issue. I was so focused on the react-navigation module, it didn't cross my mind that styling could be the issue. It's fixed and I'm leaving the link to the snack as is for anyone exploring the v3 in the future.